# How do I search bluetooth devices around me?

Tags: android, search, bluetooth

I am developing a android application, one function of this application is searching bluetooth
devices around me.

I use `startDiscovery()` and `getBondedDevices()`.

`getBondedDevices()` almost works properly! The only defect is I can not get any information for my bluetooth headset by using `myBluetoothDevice.getName().toString()` and  `myBluetoothDevice.getAddress().toString().`

As for `startDiscovery()`, It seems this function never begin to work.
Surely I have defined BroadcastReceiver and registered, following are my register code:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

I use a loop to stay in this Activity for 12 seconds in order to receive broadcast, but It  still did not work!

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: can you post your whole code?

Comment: http://www.cnblogs.com/moqiguzhu/p/3424925.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code this will help you,

https://github.com/bigamil/RetroRat/blob/master/gen/com/retrorat/v1/SearchDeviceActivity.java

Comment: Thank you! I will read your code carefully.Is "SamplesUtils" a class not included in API?